# Youtube mini player in Android app programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube

Want to realize [same functionality](https://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/nexus2cee_YT-collapse-animation.gif)(mini-player in-app only)
currently, I realized it using fragment on the foreground. But it works only when 1 activity. And if use many activities fragment will be recreated and it's not ok when user watching the video.

So, maybe someone can recommend a better solution/example.
I have checked the solution with widgets(Not for this case).

[image: youtube mini player]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise that you discarded the widget possibility but i would still recommend you check it again in this [example](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/04/introducing-home-screen-widgets-and.html).

It shows and updates data on one xml which you could expand on screen and reuse or discard if needed.